# Are there any Open d6 pre-made modules/adventures out there?

Tags: published-adventures, d6-system

I have looked and looked online but haven't found a single site that has *any* pre-made adventure for Open d6. I was hoping that someone would know of a site where I could find some.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you're probably searching for "open d6" adventures, when most publishers don't treat Open D6 as separate from *D6 System* and use the original term instead. Since "Open D6" is technically just the name of an open-licensed document that provides rules from *D6 System*, and "D6 System" has much more name recognition than "Open D6", this isn't that odd. It would be like searching for "d20 SRD adventures" when really most of those adventures are for D&D 3.5e. There are exceptions, of course, but they're rare:

- [d6 Magazine](http://wickednorthgames.com/d6-magazine/) contains Open D6 adventures, among other things

Another issue with searching for "Open D6" adventures is that many publishers are using the core of Open D6 as a foundation to build their own game on top of, and releasing adventures for *that* game specifically. Examples include [Mini Six](http://www.antipaladingames.com/p/mini-six.html), a very popular, streamlined variant of Open D6, which appears to be as or even more popular than the OGL core alone; [Mighty Six](http://mightysixenterprises.com/), a superhero RPG based on Open D6; [Heaven's Shadow](http://www.bedroomwallpress.com/p/heavens-shadow.html), an RPG that is based on Mini Six instead of directly on Open D6; and [Breachworld](http://www.breachworld.com/), another self-contained RPG based on Mini Six rather than Open D6. Some examples of such adventures written for a game based on Open D6 rather than advertised for Open D6 itself:

- [NOTB: Mission Little Rock](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/112368/NOTB-Mission-Little-Rock?filters=0_0_10020_0_0) is an adventure for [D6 Epic](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/112191/D6-Epic?filters=0_0_10020_0_0), as an example of an adventure not for Open D6, but for a system based on Open D6.
- Similarly, [The Road to Azamar](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/99280/The-Road-to-Azamar--Quick-Adventure?filters=0_0_10020_0_0) is an adventure for [Azamar the RPG](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/94517/Azamar-the-RPG?filters=0_0_10020_0_0), itself based on Open D6.

(Notably, *Azamar* is by the same studio that does *d6 Magazine*, which just underlines how small the Open D6–based segment of the RPG industry is.)

But a third part of the problem is that there just isn't much adventure support for a niche system like D6 System / Open D6, especially since it can work with any genre or setting, making an adventure "for Open D6" not necessarily useful for every GM running Open D6, and therefore much less worthwhile publishing. What's out there is mostly settings powered by Open D6, new games built on top of Open D6 (or built on top of a game built on top of Open D6!), and new rules compatible with Open D6. Adventures are mostly left up to the GM to create to suit the setting they're using, though there are a few rare exceptions, like in *d6 Magazine* or adventures for one of the RPGs based on Open D6.

The expectation really seems to be that Open D6 GMs will create their own adventures that suit their individual games, or they'll be playing with old or new D6 System material that isn't directly Open D6.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Me, along with the people whom I am to play with, are completely new to RPGs and were going to play with this system. I thought it seemed pretty fun, though I feel that it would be easier, if not better, to use a pre-made adventure for our first game.

Comment: @TheDiamante Having a pre-made adventure does make learning RPGs easier, yes. Unfortunately, starting with a free RPG and looking for free adventures does have the downside that they are quite hard to find! It's worth noting though, that *Azamar* is a free download, and so is the introductory adventure I mentioned. I haven't played them and can't recommend them personally, but downloadable and $0 does compete well with base Open D6.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a list of few OpenD6/D6 System adventures that are ready to go with the included mini setting.

- [Journey to the Forge](http://www.rpgnow.com/product/102022)
- Paranormal Investigators & Exterminators
- [Tales of War](http://www.rpgnow.com/product/102472)

While there are lots of setting books for D6 System, your question was specifically for adventures. So unless I found an adventure buried in the book, I didn't list it above. Some adventures were only ready for Mini-Six, so I only included them if the adventure included instructions on using the adventure for Open D6. The threshold being that it supports 6 attributes rather than only 4 attributes, or that it explicitly includes the OpenD6 logo.